# How to edit Google Android Code

Tags: android

I am new to google android will anyone please tell me how to edit google android code to develop my own applications?

Comment: You actually don't edit the source code of Android to make your own applications.  As others have pointed out you use their SDK to make your own applications.  Old question but want to make sure people visiting it do not get confused between building from source with modified files, and developing java/c++ applications for Android devices.

Answer (score 10):

I would start with [The Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html):

> Welcome to the Android Dev Guide! The
>   Dev Guide is a practical introduction
>   to developing applications for
>   Android. It explores the concepts
>   behind Android, the framework for
>   constructing an application, and the
>   tools for developing, testing, and
>   publishing software for the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, with the Android SDK which is free at [d.android.com](http://d.android.com)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preferred programming language: the main language for Android is Java, but it also supports scripting languages like Python and Lua. For Java, you can download the [Android SDK](http://code.google.com/android/), which should have all you need to get started. Also, check out http://developer.android.com/ for tutorials, help, docs, etc.